# React: Async function not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is my aync call `fetchButtonTeams()` below not being called. I am trying to print its results in `console.log(this.state.data)` below. Even if i call it in the render() I get infinite loops or errors. Can anyone suggest what to do?

I just want to print the results in console.log in render()

```
class TeamFilter extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = { data: [] };
    }

    async fetchButtonTeams() {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/teams`);
      const json = await response.json();
      console.log(json)
      this.setState({ data: json });
    }

    handleTeamSelection = e => {
        this.props.setTeam(e.target.title);
        this.props.fetchTeams(e.target.title)
    };


    render() {

        let test = ['Chaos', 'High Elves', 'Orcs']

        this.fetchButtonTeams()

        console.log(this.state.data)

        return (
          <DropdownButton id="dropdown-team-button" title={this.props.team_name}>
              {test.map(cls => (
                  <div key={cls}>
                      <Dropdown.Item onClick={this.handleTeamSelection} title={cls}>{cls}</Dropdown.Item>
                  </div>
              ))}
          </DropdownButton>
        )
      }


    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            team_name: state.team_name
        }
    };

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
        return {
            fetchCards: path => dispatch(fetchCards(path)),
            fetchTeams: params => dispatch(fetchTeams(params)),
            setTeam: team_name => dispatch({ type: "SET_TEAM", team_name })
        }
    };




export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TeamFilter)
```

Comment: Can you try `fetchButtonTeams = async ()  => {` and see if that works?

Comment: From where you are calling `fetchButtonTeams`?

Comment: I removed that code but how should i properly call it in render? Also @iRohitBhatia it did nothing.

Comment: @user3398034 Wait! Are you trying to call method declared inside the class from outside the class like you would call a function?

Comment: I am just trying to get the fetchButtonTeams() function to run inside render() and print the json results in console.

Comment: How do i call fetchButtonTeams() to run so it pushes the data to the data constructor.

Comment: @tyrone251 Either use fat arrow function or define function definition in constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get infinite loops when you call the function on the `render` method is because each time the function is calling `setState` which in turn runs the function again and again, triggering an infinite loop.

I don't see where you are calling `fetchButtonTeams()` anywhere in your component, but a good idea for fetching data is putting the method inside a `componentDidMount` lifecycle method and console log inside the render method.You can learn more about lifecycle hooks [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class).

For your code:

```
class TeamFilter extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchButtonTeams();
  }

  async fetchButtonTeams() {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/teams`);
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);
    this.setState({ data: json });
  }

  handleTeamSelection = e => {
    this.props.setTeam(e.target.title);
    this.props.fetchTeams(e.target.title);
  };

  render() {
    let test = ["Chaos", "High Elves", "Orcs"];

    console.log(this.state.data);

    return (
      <DropdownButton id="dropdown-team-button" title={this.props.team_name}>
        {test.map(cls => (
          <div key={cls}>
            <Dropdown.Item onClick={this.handleTeamSelection} title={cls}>
              {cls}
            </Dropdown.Item>
          </div>
        ))}
      </DropdownButton>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    team_name: state.team_name
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchCards: path => dispatch(fetchCards(path)),
    fetchTeams: params => dispatch(fetchTeams(params)),
    setTeam: team_name => dispatch({ type: "SET_TEAM", team_name })
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TeamFilter);
```

Comment: I am not calling it now since i removed that code. But how does that work?

Comment: Let me write a quick solution. Give me a sec :)

Comment: It seems to work after i added this above. 'componentDidMount(){
      this.fetchButtonTeams()
    }
'

Comment: Exactly, that's what I meant